# Spring Data: Configuring using only Java?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I am planning to introduce [Spring Data](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-data-jpa-tutorial/) to my project to act as the `Data Access Layer` to my Oracle Database.

I am unsure over the following, any resources would be very helpful:

1. How do I configure Spring-data to my database using *only* `Java` classes, no XML?
2. Do I need to use [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) as well with Spring data, to pull data from the DB?
3. Do I need to create a `SessionManager` similar to Hibernate, in order to pull data from my Repositories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use Spring Boot. It avoids XML configuration (mostly)
2. You need to use a JPA implementation, such as Hibernate. Spring Data JPA *uses* your JPA implentation, but it's pretty transparent and you don't need to worry about it much
3. Spring Data JPA creates your `EntityManager` for you, you don't need to create it yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I am currently using Spring-Boot in my project, but how/where do I configure Spring-data to tell it my JPA implementation and database connection details?

Comment: @java123999 spring-boot-starter-data-jpa maven dependency includes Hibernate by default. Use application.properties to set db connection strings. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database

Comment: Thanks, what package do I put this in in my project? This is all I need to connect to my DB?

Comment: @java123999 application.properties goes in src/main/resources/

Comment: Thank you, do you know of any resources where I can learn how to create my project structure for an application that uses spring MVC and spring data? I am struggling with this, all examples show different structures!

Comment: @java123999 I would use maven and it's standard folder structure. check their docs